# GHCi: How to make let assignments visible outside of main do

Tags: haskell

I'm a noob with Haskell and I don't know how to do the following:
  Using GHCi, in my main function, I make progressive assignments to constants.  The main purpose of this is to be able to continue analysing their contents after main has completed.  However, other than `motionFile`, which is using a bind, none of my other constants are visible.

```
main = do  
    motionFile <- readFile "transitions.mot"
    let mP = toListListDbl $ toListListStr $ dropXFromStrA 4 (lines motionFile)
    let mPT = transpose $ mP
    let mA = actuatorCurves nJ mPT
    putStrLn mA
```

After main completes, I would like to have each of the `mP`, `mPT`, and `mA` available to be inputs for other functions.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: After `main` completes, your program exits.

Comment: Yes, but the binding to motionFile persists, so I can invoke the other functions using it as a parameter.  I'm trying to make that possible for the other constants I have.

Comment: Are you doing this from the interactive interpreter? Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to say you are using other functions after `main` completes. There is no program running at that point from which you *can* call functions.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the title, but not the body of the OP, I will add that note.

Comment: You don't really need a `main` definition in GHCi; `main` is just the required entry point for a standalone-executable. Otherwise, it is no different than any other name you define during a session.

Comment: Once I have this working correctly, the executable will be used under normal circumstances.  I'm using GCHI to develop the transformations and want to be able to have the variables available to facilitate further inquiry over what is happening with the data.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I would expect `mP` and friends to be in scope if you just typed the lines after `main = do` into ghci. Is that not what you are seeing? Can you post an exact `ghci` session, along with the exact error it gives you?

Answer (score 2):

Pass them as additional arguments to your other functions.

Comment: Being new to Haskell, could you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Just move the let assignments out of your main function and define them as separate functions at top level like so

```
mP file = toListListDbl $ toListListStr $ dropXFromStrA 4 (lines file)
mPT = transpose $ mP
mA = actuatorCurves nJ mPT

main = do  
    motionFile <- readFile "transitions.mot"
    putStrLn $ mA motionFile
```

I would highly recommend you to provide type declarations like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do ...
```

and use proper function names instead of 2-3 char abbreviations.

Comment: This won't work currently, because `mP` is now a function instead of a list, so the definition of `mPT` won't type check.

Comment: Yes, and then a similar change would be made to `mA` because of how it uses `mPT`.

Comment: I have the main :: IO () declaration, just didn't include it in the code I pasted.  My plan was to expand the function/variable names once I got it to work.

Comment: Syntactically,  `mP file = toListListDbl $ toListListStr $ dropXFromStrA 4 (lines file)
mPT = transpose . mP
mA = actuatorCurves nJ . mPT`  works as @4castle pointed out.  THNX
However it doesn't quite work.  GCHI is complaining I don't have an instance for Show.